# Stack Overflow login (or other OpenID sites) - without accepting cookies from not visited 3rd party sites?

Tags: discussion, login, firefox, privacy, cookies

The login to Stack Exchange sites on Firefox only possible if you allow cookies from "not visited 3rd party sites".

That's not so nice I think, because normally you won't ever accept cookies from sites you don't visit yourself. Is there a way to do the login without allowing this?

To reproduce: In Firefox, go to `preferences -> privacy -> user defined history -> accept third-party cookies: From visited`.

Then I can't login to **Stack Overflow**.

[image: Screenshot of "Firefox - Privacy Settings"]

Comment: Right - BUT I don't want to fiddle around in the Config of my Browser just to get a login to these sites... ;-)